# Integrating MailChimp with Django User Workflow

Tags: python, django, mailchimp

I'd like to leverage the richness of mailchimp (email template design, analytics, etc) on a Django project I'm working on.

I want to essentially use Mailchimp for all email communications - new user registration on the site, forgot password, newsletters, reminders, etc.

The issue I have is that Mailchimp is very much list and campaign oriented. I'm not sure how to achieve the things listed above with the mailchimp workflow.

What I want to do is something like -

1. Setup a specific email in mailchimp, such as the 'forgot password email'
2. When a user forgets their password, I want to trigger mailchimp to send the specified mail

Does anyone have experience doing the above?

Answer (score 8):

There is a [Python API client for MailChimp](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-python) that may be worth a look.

However, MailChimp's terms and conditions actually forbid you from doing this (see http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/how-to/transactional-campaigns.php). For that, you would need to use something like [Mandrill](http://help.mandrill.com/home), which is a transactional email service offered by Mailchimp. There is an API client library for that too at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mandrill/, and it looks like there are a few third party libraries too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw mandrill previously, but was under the impression it's more of the sending-mail layer (slightly more than SES). The attractive thing with mailchimp is the richness provided above sending mail - eg. analytics, mail styling via the UI, etc. Do you know if Mandrill provides that level of features?

Comment: It looks like Mandrill does offer similar functionality to Mailchimp, but I don't have personal experience with it. It does look like it's free for the first 12,000 emails each month so there's plenty of scope to try it out and see if it fits your needs without commitment.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have create an account on MailChimp, create the List there, and thereafter get the List Key and API key of your account.

Install the package to integrate MailChimp into your Django site

```
pip install mailchimp
```

Then send a request to connect with your list in MailChimp

```
import mailchimp

API_KEY = <<Your MailChimp API Key>>
LIST_ID = <<Your List Key>>
api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)
api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'})
```

For a detailed explanation and integration step by step, follow this tutorial:
https://djangopy.org/package-of-week/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-on-django-to-increase-subscribers/

Comment: Note, `mailchimp` is for V2 API, https://pypi.org/project/mailchimp3/ looks fairly maintained package for V3

Answer (score 0):

We are using MailSnake FWIW which claims to support both Mandrill and MailChimp

https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-mailsnake

Comment: Note: it doesn't yet support V3 API https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-mailsnake/issues/28